# Comments and reference-request on books for KK-theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, index-theory, kk-theory

I am looking for a good reference to learn Kasparov's KK-theory, where my motivation is to understand (and hopefully can do something about) the Atiyah-Singer index theorem in terms of KK-theory.

I happen to have a copy of "An introduction to K-theory for $C^*$-algebra" by Larsen-Laustsen, and a copy of "Analytic K-homology" by Higson-Roe. However, after some googling it seems that the books "K-Theory for Operator Algebras" by Blackadar and "Elements of KK-theory" by Jensen-Thomsen are closer to what I want. I have also read the reviews of these four books in MathSciNet but couldn't decide which one is more suitable for my purpose. For my background, well, let say I only know the basic definition of $C^*$-algebra, and some knowledge in topological $K$-theory.

How would you comment on these four books? And which one is more suitable for index theory? Other references are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have both of the books you mentioned but didn't own. For sure the better one is "K-Theory for Operator Algebras" by Blackadar, if your goal is the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem. First, this book explicitly discusses the Index Theorem as a motivation, throughout. Second, in chapter 18, it discusses how parts of Atiyah and Singer's proof go over to the KK-theory world. Lastly, Chapter 24 is titled "Survey of Applications to Geometry and Topology," and starts with the line "In this section, we give a brief survey of the principal applications of KK-theory so far in geometry and topology." The first subsection is "Index Theorems" and starts with the Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem. Also, subsection 5 is "KK-theoretic proofs."

Conversely, the Jensen-Thomsen book says almost nothing at all about index theorems, and I could not find any mention of the work of Atiyah and Singer (not in the references, the book's index, or through an electronic search of the book). I didn't check the other two books you mentioned because you said you already had them.

Comment: How is it compared with Efimov's algebraic KK-theory mentioned in https://youtu.be/tUMOOmwKXyA

Comment: I am unaware of any book by Efimov on the subject. The question was to compare four specific books, to see which was best for the connection to the Atiyah Singer index theorem

Comment: Thank you Professor @DavidWhite